# Kendo Datepicker disables "today" if using min declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am fighting a weird problem concerning declaration of datepicker using min.  I want to be able to click the "today" button in the footer of the calendar but it is "greyd out" and unclickable.

If I exclude the min declaration then everything works fine, such as this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
  .Name("DatePicker")
  .Value(DateTime.Now)
  .Format("dd.MMMM yyyy")
  .Max(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6))
  //.Min(DateTime.Now)
)
```

But if I remove the comment slashes then I can not click the "today" link.  I viewed [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/rangeselection) and saw that the "today" button was disabled if the date range did not include today, but my dates do in fact include today.

I even tried expanding the date range but that did not work either.

Can anyone spot my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has a very simple solution. Change "DateTime.Now" to "DateTime.Today" and everything will work as you expect. i.e.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
         .Name("DatePicker")
         .Value(DateTime.Now)
         .Format("dd.MMMM yyyy")
         .Max(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6))
         .Min(DateTime.Today)
        )
```

Hope this helps.:)

Comment: Haha wow that did the trick.  Man!  How could I miss that, silly me.  Thanx :)